# .NET　でロードバランサがある場合の送信元IPアドレス取得方法

Tags: windows, .net, socket

#### 前提

現在以下の構成で TCP サーバアプリケーションを作成しています。

```
PC(クライアント)＜──インターネット──＞ロードバランサ ───────サーバ１
                        │─────────────────────────────サーバ２
                        │─────────────────────────────サーバ３
```

サーバアプリケーションとしては .NET Framework の `Socket` クラスを使用しています。

ソケットクラスに指定しているパラメタとしては

- `AddressFamily＃InterNetwork`
- `SocketType＃Stream`
- `ProtocolType＃Tcp`

インスタンス生成時、上記を設定（ TCP 送受信設定）しています。

また、環境は以下です。

- クライアント PC：Windows 7
- サーバ：Windowws Server2012
- ロードバランサ：BIG-IP
- 開発言語：C++/CLI
- 実行環境：.NET Framework 4.5
- プログラム作成環境：Visual Studio Pro 2012

### 質問事項

以下のコードで、本来は接続されたクライアントのIPアドレスを取得出来る想定でしたが、ロードバランサのIPアドレスが取得されます。

以下擬似コード

```
Socket ClientSocket = ServerSocket.EndAccept(iAsyncResult);
String IpAddress = ((IPEndPoint)ClientSocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(IpAddress);

--------------
出力結果：ロードバランサのIPアドレス
--------------
```

WireShark を使用してパケットモニタリングし、調査した結果、 IP ヘッダにはクライアント PC のIPアドレスが入っていることがわかりました。おそらく、プログラムで取得するやり方が悪いのだと思われるのですが、 IP ヘッダに記載されている IP アドレスを取得する方法がわかりません。

少しでも良いのでヒントになる情報があれば、ご教授くださると助かります。

Comment: WireSharkで確認したのはどこのパケットでしょうか？ サーバー上で受信したパケットであれば挙げられたコードで取得できます。

Comment: サーバー上で受信したパケットを確認しました。
しかし、上記コードでは取得できないのです。。。

Comment: モニタしたパケットにはクライアントPCのIPアドレスが含まれているということなので、`Socket`クラスのプロパティに頼らず、バイト配列から自前で読み取る必要があるのではないでしょうか。[RawSocket(System.Net.Sockets.Socket)を使ってIPv4ヘッダを読み込み、パケットモニタを作る](http://kazuhirokazu.hateblo.jp/entry/20111223/1324574391) という記事が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: クライアントアドレスはIPヘッダーのどこに格納されていたのでしょうか？ 何の説明もないと送信元アドレスと受け取るのが自然ですが。オプションフィールドの場合、yukitosさんの提案されている方法が考えられますが、しかし、その方法をとると今度はTCPパケットを送信することはできないので、期待するものではないかもしれません。

Comment: BIG-IP(に限らずたいていのロードバランサ)にはクライアントのIPアドレスをそのまま通すモードとNATするモードがあります。どっちになってますか。

Comment: 送信元IPは、IPヘッダの送信元IPに格納されていることを確認しました。
また、ロードバランサの設定ではハーフNAT（宛先IPアドレスのみ変更）の設定になっていました。

Answer (score 2):

考えられるのは

1. .NETのバグ
2. プログラムのバグ
3. クライアントのアドレスがNATされている
4. 実際にロードバランサとサーバが通信している

と言うところでしょうか(順不同)。

英語版にも同様の質問がありましたが、proxyじゃないのか、という回答がついてます。

[Socket.RemoteEndPoint returns gateway address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222140/socket-remoteendpoint-returns-gateway-address)

コメントと重複するところもありますが、一般論として確認する項目や方法を列挙しておきます。

### トレース情報の出力

[トレース情報の出力を有効](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ty48b824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)にすることで、Socketのトレースがとれます。

```
System.Net.Sockets Information: 0 : [4292] Socket#45653674 - 192.168.1.2:58849 から 192.168.1.1:22222 への接続を受け入れました。
```

### netstat

```
C:\> netstat -n
  アクティブな接続

  プロトコル  ローカル アドレス          外部アドレス        状態
  TCP    127.0.0.1:22222        127.0.0.1:51819        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.1:22222      192.168.1.2:58849      ESTABLISHED
```

不要分を省略してますが、この例だとサーバのポート(22222)に対して2つの接続があります。

クライアント-サーバの接続が正しく表示されていますか？また、ロードバランサ-サーバの接続がありませんか？

### パケットダンプ

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)等のネットワークアナライザでパケットを取得し確認する。

このとき注意することとしては、「自分の意図どおりのパケット」以外にも注目することです。

今回の例では、PC-サーバ宛てのパケットが「意図通りのパケット」に当たりますが、実はそのパケットではコネクションが張れていないとか、それ以外にロードバランサ-サーバ間の通信が実際に存在したりしませんか。

### ロードバランサ

ロードバランサは(設計)設定によってクライアントだったりサーバだったりのアドレスを変換します。どのような設定になっているか確認してください。

また、ヘルスチェックを行っている場合、ロードバランサがサーバに接続します。これが意図しない不具合を起こす場合もあります。(ソケットが埋まるなど)

Answer (score 2):

WebRequestではなくSocketを使っていることから、HTTP以外のプロトコルかな？という気もしますが、仮にHTTPであれば、BIG-IPがアドレスを付け替えた際に、HTTPヘッダにX-Forwarded-Forヘッダを付けます。

http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

で、HTTPヘッダに情報が乗っていればWebRequest.Headersプロパティから取得できると思います。（試してませんが・・・）